# How can I apply a clip-path after/during animation?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a path in SVG defining a clipPath. Lines (tick marks) are drawn and clipped to the path.

When I perform an animation of the lines, they retain the original clipping. I would like them to be 're-clipped' at each stage of the animation.

**Question**: Is there an easy way to have the clipping performed during the transition?

Sample problem code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q29TA/

When you click on the svg, it demonstrates the animation.

Relevant snippets:

```
d3.select( "#g-container" )
  .selectAll( "line" )
  .data( y.ticks( 10 ) )
  .enter()
    .append( "line" )
    .attr( "x1", 0 ).attr( "x2", width )
    .attr( "y1", y ).attr( "y2", y )
    .attr( "class", "tick-marks" )
    .attr( "clip-path", "url(#myclip)" );​

d3.select( "svg" )          
    .on("click", function() {
       d3.selectAll(".tick-marks")
          .transition().duration( 2500 )
          .attr( "transform", "translate(0,30)" )
    } )
```

I am open to new ways of doing this, but I can't hardcode an animation that recomputes the line's x1 and x2, since the clipPath could be anything.

Sample picture showing the aftermath of animation (I want the horizontal lines to meet the blue, diagonal line of the container):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use a single clip-path, just move the `clip-path` up to the container `g` element instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/dxZyq/

Comment: Setting this as the answer, even though the answer from @meetamit works. This solution is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

So (as you've discovered) it seems that clipping paths disregard the elements' `transform` properties. You could see it also happening – even without animation – if you apply your transform right when the elements are created:

```
.enter()
  .append( "line" )
  .attr( "transform", "translate(0,30)" )// <-- Same, "wrong" (i.e. undesired) clipping
  .attr( "x1", 0 ).attr( "x2", width )
  .attr( "y1", y ).attr( "y2", y )
  .attr( "class", "tick-marks" )
  .attr( "clip-path", "url(#myclip)" );​
```

From messing around, I've found that one way around this issue is grouping all the elements that need to move and translating just the group. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q29TA/2/ (note, I'm just translating the group you created, which also has the blue path in it, so it's not quite right).

The other way of getting around it is not to apply the transform, and instead, move the lines by animating their `y1` and `y2`: http://jsfiddle.net/Q29TA/1/

Comment: The former (shifting the group) doesn't work for my use case, but the animation of y1,y2 works great. Thanks!

Comment: clip-path doesn't disregard `transform` attributes, it just defaults to the `userSpaceOnUse` coordinate system (which happens to be affected by `transform`). See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipPathElementClipPathUnitsAttribute.